# Where to draw in libGDX

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, screen, extend

i made a game in libGDX for android. I made a main screen that extends game, i also have blank screen and a game screen where you actually play the game. My question is where do i create and where do i render the game. i tried to create a texture in the main screen and render in the game screen. but i get erros.

Main Screen:

```
package com.mygdx.paper;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Main extends Game {


    Blank blankScreen;
    Game gameScreen;


   @Override
    public void create() {
            blackScreen = new blankScreen(this);
            gameScreen = new blankScreen(this);
            setScreen(blankScreen); 

    }
 }
```

Blank Screen:

```
package com.mygdx.paper;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

public class Blank implements Screen {

Main main; 

public Blank(Main main) {
    this.main= main;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) 
        main.setScreen(main.gameScreen);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

Game Sceen

My game screen has everything in it like create, render.
But it does not work when i click on the blank screen.

Comment: Typo: blackScreen should be blankScreen?

Comment: Thankyou for that, but can you help me with my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? What were you expecting, what actually happened? Based on the code you provided it will set itself to blankScreen and then when you touch it, it will set itself to blankScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
blackScreen = new blankScreen(this);
gameScreen = new blankScreen(this);
```

you set a new blankScreen instance for both screens: blackScreen *and* gameScreen. So after touching your blankScreen you will see anther blankScreen an so on..

You might actually want to actually assign a GameScreen (..or whatever your games screen's class is actually called) instead:

```
gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
```

BTW: there is a really nice [tutorial about screens in libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game)

Answer (score 0):

```
blackScreen = new Blank(this);
gameScreen = new Blank (this);
```

but nothing will happen in UI because the screen stays black

Comment: In the blank screen i say, if i touch the screen, it must go to the game screen. but it doesn't go. what i see is just black screen. But if i just play the code of my game screen, it works, but i want to go from one screen to another screen where i can play the game. But in the game class i have render method, create method and things. but it seems that if you impement Screen, then the draw method won't work. so i want to know where i can create things, and where i can draw things and render it.

Comment: I can not understand what you want , is this your real code? In this code blankScreen and gameScreen are instances of Blank so nothing will change in thr graphical part of your game